# TLS connection handshake Failure

Tags: c#, ssl, paypal, https

We have difficulties to make https connections to the remote machines (like PayPal vb.) who disabled SSL3 protocol from our .Net application. We are getting following exception on GetResponse method of HttpWebRequest instance.

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

When we go depth and trace network logs with WireShark, we see that remote machine return the following error

> TLSv1.2   Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure) 
>   Handshake Failure 40

More interesting situation is when I try enter to PayPal address to the internet browser, it can successfully open the page, which means that connection can be established,
We also try to connect with OpenSSL command tool, result is again succesfully connected.

When we compare the WireShark logs of InternetExplorer and .Net application we can see that Internet Explorer is sending more available cipher suites than .Net application,
and also PayPal is selecting the following cipher which is not in .Net applications requests.

> TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

Followings are captured logs from WireShark:

**ServerMachine:.Net application Client Hello** [image: .Net application Client Hello]
**ServerMachine:.Net application Server Response** [image: .Net application Server Response]
**ServerMachine:InternetExplorer Client Hello** [image: IE Client Hello]
**ServerMachine:InternetExplorer Server Hello** [image: IE Server Hello]

Followings are captured from our development machines which is working without a problem.
**DevMachine:.Net application Client Hello** [image: .Net application Client Hello on dev enviroment]
**DevMachine:.Net application Server Hello** [image: .Net application Server Hello on dev enviroment]

What we think that PayPal doesn't like our Cipher Suites that we send on "Client Hello" request from .Net application.

More more interesting situation is this problem only occured on our production machines which are running Windows 2008 R2, everythins is working on our dev enviroment with Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 8 pcs.

Please give us some idea to solve this problem.

Following is our C# code to connect PayPal api.

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/");

wr.Method = "POST";
wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


string output = null;
try
{
    WebResponse wres = wr.GetResponse();
    Stream ress = wres.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader ressr = new StreamReader(ress, Encoding.UTF8);
    output = ressr.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (System.Net.WebException webEx)
{
    if (webEx.Response != null)
    {
        WebResponse wres = webEx.Response;
        Stream ress = wres.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader ressr = new StreamReader(ress);
        output = ressr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    else
        throw webEx;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Have you enabled TLS 1.1 & 1.2 in Internet Options in dev but not in production (for the 2k8R2 boxes, in 2012, IIRC, they are enabled by default)?

Comment: Hello Richard, I enabled all of them in IE settings, but .Net application still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know anything that why .Net doesn't send the required cipher which is sended by IE

Comment: NO, I was just asking the most obvious possible root cause. If it is not that you need someone who knows more about this area.

Comment: See the GPEDIT note here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx - See if TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is listed, if not add it. (in a corp environment you may need to speak to the admin if this is applied @ the domain level)

Comment: On reflection if it works in IE I doubt that's the cause :/

Comment: Does forcing the [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) to use TLS work? `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What we think that PayPal doesn't like our Cipher Suites that we send on "Client Hello" request from .Net application.

This is correct. If you look at [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com) you will see, that api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com supports only RC4-SHA (TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA) which is not included in your cipher set.

> More more interesting situation is this problem only occured on our production machines which are running Windows 2008 R2

It might be that you've added some hardening to the production systems and disabled RC4-SHA, because this cipher is considered insecure. See [Microsoft Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx) for a matching recommendation which you have probably implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steffen, ssllabs reports is a very good resource to see the PayPal supported cipher suites.
When I looked to the updated that is installed our server I see the KB2868725 is installed this makes get closed the cause.
But we have another server 2008 and also has this update too and this pc is working well. :(
Also we can connect to payPal by Internet Explorer from the pc that can't connect with .Net application :( this is another obscure problem

Comment: Hello, its because of the update that you wrote, and .Net Security Update 2960358(Update for Disabling RC4 in .NET TLS) which is restrict .Net applications to use RC4. Thanks for your helps