# LDAP configuration with PHP + IIS

Tags: php, iis, openssl, ldap

I am working on some 3rd party integration project.

Created RootCA and SubCA from their official documentation website and after importing in windows server, we created key using openssl and got signed certificate from 3rd party integration Support team

We have configured in `ldp.exe` client and it got connected and fetched the dataset.

Now we are implementing in PHP code level.

We have:

- IIS server 10
- PHP 7.2
- PHP Code is working in IIS
- Added `ldap.conf` file created `c:/openldap/sysconf/ldap.conf`

  ```
    TLS_REQCERT allow
    #TLS_CACERT c:\openldap\sysconf\RootCaSha1.der
    TLS_CACERT c:\openldap\sysconf\SubCaSha1.der
    #TLS_CACERTDIR c:\openldap\sysconf
  ```

We have tried various paths and noted all evidence via `wireshark` tool

It says `TLSv1.2    Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)` so it means some certificate in `ldap.conf` are not as per requirement.

Looking forward to help in this regard so we can get connect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the TLS handshake failure error commonly occurred when the server’s certificate is configured improperly. this should be configured on the IIS server-side. Please check the below items.
The account running the website is supposed to own the right of accessing the private key of the certificate. Firstly import the certificate to the Local machine Certification Store, under the property page of the certificate, grant the account access to the private key of the certificate.
[image]
Subsequently, we specify the certificate in the IIS site binding module.
[image]
Besides, Please note that the communication between the client-side and the server-side is established based on the fact that the client trusts the server certificate. this means that when we visit the website, the browser address bar has the sign of security lock. In this way, the public key of the certificate can be exchanged. The specific operation is to add the server root certificate to the Trusted Root Certificate Authority certification store of the client-side.
[image]

Comment: We have verified this and all seems OK. meanwhile we are trying using FQDN (private url) and maybe due to that its not working.

Comment: Does the client OS/SDK support TLS1.2? such as the Windows server2008, you have to install certain updates to support TLS1.2
Check this discussion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802089/tls-connection-handshake-failure

Comment: Yes I checked the wireshark. `client hello` contains version 1.0 while `server hello` contains version 1.2 for TLS. Right now I am trying to focus on SSL on local machine in IIS. meanwhile whats the possibility of configuring SSL on Local IIS. (coz i have worked in xampp but not on IIS)

Comment: As far as I know, TLS version is shipped by OS/DotNet SDK. There is no way to configure it in the IIS.
http://sunlync.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=623
Try to install the latest DotNet framework or the below update.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi

Comment: ok thanks for your guidance. I will try these and update you.

Comment: HI, any clue how I can do with PHP level to connect ldap with certificates

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with PHP. Please refer to the official manual.
https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.ldap-connect.php
Also, try the below solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232950/php-ldap-connection

Comment: Yes that I have tried. 
Anyway thank you for your support somehow issue is at transportation layer.